# I need help using a Vlookup in vba

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub vlookup()

Dim LR as Integer
LR = Range(“A” & Row.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range(“D2”).Formula=“=Vlookup(A2,’[yGL dcs.xlsx]GL       ENTERED INV raw data’!C$4:C$”$LR&”,1,false)
Range(“D2”).Copy
Range(“D2:D” & LR).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End sub
```

I need to perform a vlookup in column D in workbook1 and compare it to column C in workbook2. My code gives me an error stating “end of statement on the vlookup line.

Comment: you have a `$` where you should have `&` but you should also have spaces on either side of the `&`

Comment: Not your problem but `LR` should be `Dim`ed as `Long`: there are more rows in Excel than `Integer`'s limit. Do you really have all those spaces in the sheet name?  Do you have curly quotes in your code? All that said, you have a typo:  `”$LR&”` should be `" & LR & "`

Comment: You are also missing a closing `"`

Comment: Now it is giving me an error on the line beginning with LR. When I click to debug, it highlights the whole line. How do I fix this?

Comment: "Now it is giving me an error" - if you changed something in your code you can update your question to add it, along with a description of any error you're getting...